# skip focus from TAB jump

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph with various html elements. Some links, some input boxes, etc. The TAB button changes focus from the current element to the next html element: it jumps from link to link. Is it possible to set a specific html element to be "skipped" from such focus from the TAB button?

Comment: Here's a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561021/prevent-tabstop-on-a-element-anchor-link-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore HTML element from tabindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/how-to-ignore-html-element-from-tabindex)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `tabindex` attribute controls tabbing. Set it to `-1` and the tab key will not stop on that element.

```
<input tabindex="-1" />
```

Set it to a non-negative number and you can control the tab order.  From the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex):

> The following elements support the tabindex attribute: `A`, `AREA`,
>   `BUTTON`, `INPUT`, `OBJECT`, `SELECT`, and `TEXTAREA`.

In *[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)* you can use the `tabindex` attribute on *any* element. From [HTML5 differences from HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-attributes):

> Several attributes from HTML4 now apply to all elements. These are called global attributes: `accesskey`, `class`, `dir`, `id`, `lang`, `style`, `tabindex` and `title`.

Comment: Keep in mind that programmatically, it is tabIndex. The camel case is important.