# Prevent focus on <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent tabstop on A element (anchor link) in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561021/prevent-tabstop-on-a-element-anchor-link-in-html)

see this link first [sample layout](http://jsfiddle.net/jrsalunga/fUPSL/)

does anyone know to prevent visiting/focus on  link when I press TAB key and automatically go to the next input?

Comment: Use tabindex="-1" attribute on the link.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561021/prevent-tabstop-on-a-element-anchor-link-in-html][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561021/prevent-tabstop-on-a-element-anchor-link-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a custom [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1) for the elements to skip the link.