# Prevent tabbing to link when hidden by parent element with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I have a scrollable `div` with a list of links in it. Even though I have set the div to `overflow:hidden`, to hide some of the links, they are still accessible when tabbing in the browser. Is there a way to prevent this without using jquery?

```html
<div style="height: 5rem; overflow: hidden">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain what do you need from this?

Comment: I need to prevent the hyper link from being keyboard tab accessible if they are not visible on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, not to my knowledge.  This is because `overflow: hidden;` is a visual modifier only and is not intended to limit functionality.  That's the way accessibility is intended to work. You must remove the functionality of an item in the DOM by hiding it (`display: none`, `visibility: hidden`), disabling it, or removing it from `tabIndex` by setting the individual elements to `tabIndex="-1"`.  Since the CSS can't really tell what is hidden and what isn't like jQuery can (psuedo classes haven't come that far yet), jQuery is still likely your best bet.

Here's some good extra info for you: [Tabbing causes overflow content to shift up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520956/tabbing-causes-overflow-content-to-shift-up)

Comment: Is there an easy way to do it with Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: @Eric No, but there are a couple libraries out there that might help.