# Bootstrap > Prevent Scrolling To Hash When Using Tab Key

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, hashtag

this is driving me a bit nuts.

Please go to http://getbootstrap.com/components/

And use the tab key...please see that the page scrolls (cycles-to) the next item with a hashtag when you click the tab key.

How can I disable this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561021/prevent-tabstop-on-a-element-anchor-link-in-html  (and probably others)  It's browser behaviour to jump to the next anchor or input, for accessibility (eg if you can't use a mouse).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "tabindex" to "-1". But it is standard behaviour of web browsers...